# Have AngularJS perform logic on form inputs when form submits

Tags: angularjs, forms

I currently have a form like the following:

```
<form autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="{{trustSrc(SUBMIT_URL)}}">
  <input type="text" name="firstinput" ng-model="first"/>
  <input type="text" name="secondinput" ng-model="second"/>
  <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

And a controller like so:

```
$scope.first = "first";
$scope.second = "second";

$scope.SUBMIT_URL = DATABASE_URL + "forms/submit/";

$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
};
```

And when I submit this form as is, it works just fine with the backend. However I now need to use `ng-submit` in place of the standard HTML form submit because I need to run a find and replace in `$scope.first`. The backend expects the data to be posted exactly in the way the original HTML form does. How do I use `$http` or `$resource` to post in the exact same format as the HTML form?

Comment: Fixed my form to show my form submit. And I'm not very familiar with the HTML form - it seems to make some sort of `xhr`, and if I had to guess, I'd assume it is the native `xhr`. There aren't many resources online that explain what `<form>` does when submitted so I haven't been able to find out much.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish. But, you should tidy up your code a bit, to make the implementation easier:

- Don't use different variables for each input's field. Instead, use an object with different keys.
- Use `ng-click` (or `ng-submit`) for your submission. Action will go inside your JS logic.
- Use the `novalidate` attribute so that Angular can properly format, and validate your form on its own (and you don't get confusing cross-browser effects).

With those in mind, your new markup would be:

```
<form autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="first" ng-model="form.first" />
    <input type="text" name="second" ng-model="form.second" />
    <button ng-click="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Your JS directive is then:

```
app.directive('form', function($http)
{
    return function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        // Leave this empty if you don't have an initial data set
        scope.form = {
            first  : 'First Thing To Write',
            second : 'Second item'
        }

        // Now submission is called
        scope.submit = function()
        {
            // You have access to the variable scope.form
            // This contains ALL of your form and is in the right format
            // to be sent to an backend API call; it will be a JSON format

            // Use $http or $resource to make your request now:
            $http.post('/api/call', scope.form)
                 .success(function(response)
                 {
                    // Submission successful. Post-process the response
                 })
        }
    }
});
```